# watchkitapp.app: No such file or directory

Tags: ios

I just added two new `Scheme` for my iOS application, Schemes are `Debug`, `Release`, `OTA Debug` and `OTA Release`.

When I try to **Archive** application on `OTA Release` the following error appears.

```
error: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/AppName/BuildProductsPath/OTA Release-watchos/watchkitapp.app: No such file or directory
```

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted OTA schemes and created again, The issue fixed.